# ROW_NUMBER() and Mathematical functions in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I couldn't find an answer to this specific to BigQuery. Basically I want to be able to count ROW_NUMBER in a query and then modify the row number with basic math operators (add, subtract, etc) without using a subquery.

I know the following code works, but to me it seems unnecessary to use a subquery just to append basic math operators

```
SELECT
  id,
  title,
  language,
  rn+5
FROM
(
  SELECT
    id,
    title,
    language,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS rn
  FROM [publicdata:samples.wikipedia] LIMIT 1000
)
```

However when I try to add the plus sign without the subquery I get an error

```
SELECT
  id,
  title,
  language,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER() +5  AS rn_offset,
FROM [publicdata:samples.wikipedia] LIMIT 1000
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible in BigQuery without a subquery, or is my syntax in error?

Thanks,
Onji

Comment: You have a trailing `,` before the `FROM` clause

Comment: in BigQuery Legacy SQL trailing `,` before `FROM` clause is not a problem at all!

Comment: @onji I can agree with you on the fact that `using subquery just to append with basic match operator` can seem as unnecessary - BUT at the same time I see no practical use of your example at all! What would be reason for you to increase `ROW_NUMBER()` inline with row_number() itself. if there is some further use of it  - it should be reflected there which most likely anyway will involve subquery. Anyway  - can you give your exact `practical` use case?

Comment: @Siyual. Yep that was my bad, ugly code. As Mikhail said BigQuery Legacy doesn't care about the trailing comma. Still I try not to leave them in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation of BigQuery's legacy SQL - various computations cannot be composed without using a subselect. It is unfortunate, but unlikely to be changed at this point. This is just one example among many.

However, you can do this in [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/) without a subquery:

```
SELECT
  id,
  title,
  language,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER() +5  AS rn_offset
FROM `publicdata.samples.wikipedia` LIMIT 1000
```

If limitations like this annoy you while using legacy SQL, I suggest looking into using standard SQL.

Comment: This is great, I didn't know about the option to enable standard SQL. I've been hoping for Google to make BigQuery more standardised and less quirky.

Thanks Danny!